# How do i achieve this output in my menu dropdown

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I dont really no how to explain my question to get my expected result from readers but in soluction i need idea or soluction on How to code my css to output  like this picture below in html menu dropdown

[image: expected output]

this my tried code:

```css
a {
  color: #4C9CF1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
  color: #555;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

#menu-icon {
  display: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #4C8FEC url(menu-icon.png) right;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
}

a:hover#menu-icon {
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

section {
  margin: 80px auto 40px;
  max-width: 980px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px
}


/*MEDIA QUERY*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  header {
    position: absolute;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav ul,
  nav:active ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    center: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
  }
  nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

but it output my menu dropdown like this
[image: my current output]

what should i do big thanks for your time and impact in my soluction

Comment: Begin with removing `width: 100%` from `nav li`. Then it's just a ply with paddings/margin, etc.

Comment: @panther
am sorry i can't really get your idea can give a code edition of your idea in answers?

Comment: Sorry, don't want to code it now. You need to put both (icon and menu) into one line (using float or inline-block for both, without positioning). Then you need to remove 100% width for `ul`. Now you need to align `li` into one row, again, remove 100% width. It's all the magic.

Comment: puting both (icon and menu) into
one line (using float or
inline-block for both,
without positioning). Ohh i have no knowledge of this i just note few in css which i could achieve this

Comment: _Ohh i have no knowledge of this i just note few in css which i could achieve this_... sorry I can't to teach you CSS basics.

Comment: Anyway? Thanks for impact in my soluction just want to achieve this output that all am not living in css if i got this early as you just sayed css basic no room for my question just thought am on the right site loaded with big kings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First One:

https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/9wkavvd0/1/

Second One:

https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/9wkavvd0/2/

Hello There!

Maybe this what you are looking to do

First One

```css
a {
  color: #4C9CF1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
  color: #555;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

#menu-icon {
  display: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #4C8FEC url(menu-icon.png) right;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
}

a:hover#menu-icon {
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

section {
  margin: 80px auto 40px;
  max-width: 980px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px
}


/*MEDIA QUERY*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  header {
    position: absolute;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav{
    display:flex;
  }
  nav ul,
  nav:active ul {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 0px 0px 1px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
  }
  nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Second One:

```css
a {
  color: #4C9CF1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
  color: #555;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

#menu-icon {
  display: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #4C8FEC url(menu-icon.png) right;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
}

a:hover#menu-icon {
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

section {
  margin: 80px auto 40px;
  max-width: 980px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px
}


/*MEDIA QUERY*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  header {
    position: absolute;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav{
    display:flex;
  }
  nav ul,
  nav:active ul {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 0px 0px 1px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
  }
  nav li {
padding: 4px 8px 10px 5px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem just use the flexbox!

```
.nav {
   display: flex;
   padding: 20px
}

nav li {
   flex: 1
}
```

Set the nav to `display: flex` to show both elements in one line. Remove width of 100% from `li` and set a `flex:1` so it expands to the given space. If you want to set a max-width - just set it with a value of your joice to bind it to a max expand range.

Remove the following

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

Further infos about the flexbox: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp